# Access &compare 2 schema's keys in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, rest

I have 2 schema's ( Job & Company )

```
const jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    company: {type: String, required: true },
);
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
logo: {type:String},
);
```

in different files i did import & export
both have the same values (job.company & company.name )
i want to compare them and add the logo in job schema based on compassion

```
router.get('/company-logo', (req, res) => {

  Company.find({name:{$eq:Job.company}})
      // Return all 
      .then((company) => {
        res.status(200).json({ logo :company });
      })
      // Catch any errors that might occur
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do is set a relation between your schemas.  For instance, if you wanted to show that a job is within a certain company you could set the models up like this:

```
const jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    company: {type: Schem.Type.ObjectId, ref: "Company", required: true},
});

const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    logo: {type:String},
    jobs: {type: Schem.Type.ObjectId, ref: "Job", required: false}
});
```

This sets references to each model by linking a job to a certain company.  With this set up you could then do the below, assuming you have the job on your request:

```
router.get('/company-logo', (req, res) => {
  try{

  const job = new Job(req.body);

  const company = await Company.findById({_id: job.company})

  res.status(200).json({ logo: company.logo });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
```

This assumes a 1:1 relationship, so in case this is 1:many or many:many then you would need to set references up as arrays.  If you want to dive further into that then check out this article:

https://dev.to/oluseyeo/how-to-create-relationships-with-mongoose-and-node-js-11c8